# R's gc() on parallel runs seems to dramatically under-report peak memory

Tags: r, parallel-processing, garbage-collection

In R I have a task that I'm trying to parallelize. Part of this is comparing run-times and peak memory usage for different implementations of the task at hand. I'm using the `peakRAM` library to determine peak memory, which I think just uses `gc()` under the surface, since if I do it manually I get the same peak memory results.

The problem is that the results from `peakRAM` are different from the computer's task manager (or `top` on Linux). If I run a single-core, these numbers are in the same ballpark, but even using 2 cores, they are really different.

I'm parallelizing using `pblapply` in a manner similar to this.

```
times_parallel = peakRAM(
        pblapply(X = 1:10,
                 FUN = \(x) data[iteration==x] %>% parallel_task(),
                 cl = makeCluster(numcores, type = "FORK"))
    )
```

With a single core, this process requires a peak of 30G of memory. But with 2 cores, `peakRAM` reports only about 3G of memory. Looking at `top` however, shows that each of the 2 threads is using around 20-30G of memory at a time.

The only thing I can think of is that `peakRAM` is only reporting the memory of the main thread but I see nothing in the `gc()` details that suggests this is happening.

The time reported from `peakRAM` seems appropriate. Sub-linear gains at different core levels.

Comment: My guess would be that `peakRAM::peakRAM()` only profiles the memory of the current R process - not the parallel R processes running in background.  `base::gc()` is only reporting on memory use in the current R process.

Comment: That fits what I'm seeing. Anyway to see memory use across all processes?